# How to determine why apache gracefully shut itself down?

Tags: apache-2.4, httpd

I have apache httpd 2.4.6 running on RHEL 7.9
Yesterday the service was shut down, and the only information I am getting from /etc/httpd/error_log-DATE is from the last line of the file:

[mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1682] AH00170: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully

prior to this line, there are no other exceptional error message, aside from a few PHP notices, which I doubt are critical (PHP Notice:  A non well formed numeric
value encountered)

Is there any other log file that I can investigate on what caused the graceful shutdown?

Comment: You might found something useful for your case [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/780853/what-is-in-apache-2-a-caught-sigwinch-error)